# Join two tables sortby user click count then everyone click count using linq

Tags: c#, linq, join, favorites

I'm new to linq and I need a certain join. So I have two tables for certain pages I want to join with Linq that are something like

**UserFavorites** table:

```
Page.id
userClickCount
```

**Page** table:

```
id
everyoneClickCount
```

A user favorite is created when it's clicked or made a favorite so there are only a certain amount of links. I want to show all results from both tables, sort them by the most clicked by the user, then most clicked by everyone.

I have this right now but it sorts by the everyone count.

```
pages = (from page in context.Page
              join ps in
          (from favs in context.UserFavorites
              select favs) on page.Id equals ps.Page.Id into temp
          from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
              orderby t.userClickCount descending, t.Page.everyoneClickCount  descending, t.Page.PageName ascending
            select dash).ToList();
```

I'm just not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You're not filtering on the current user anywhere...

Comment: Does page have a navigation property `UserFavorites`? And, is this linq to sql?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var pages = context.Pages.Select(page => new { 
                                               PageData = page, 
                                               Favs = page.UserFavorites 
                                             })
                         .OrderByDescending(page => (page.Fav.Sum(userClickCount))
                         .ThenBy(page => page.PageData.everyoneClickCount)
                         .ThenBy(page => page.PageData.Name)
                         .ToList();
```

Note that this will order by the sum of *all* users' click counts.  If you just want the current user, replace that line with `.OrderByDescending(page => (page.Fav.Where(u => u.userID == userid).Sum(userClickCount))`

Answer (score -3):

For complex joins I suggest writing a stored procedure and then using EF and linq to call this SP.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I need to learn stored procedures anyway. Thanks

Comment: This isn't a complex join, and using stored procedures greatly increases the complexity of maintaining the code.

Comment: And, on top of what Bobson says, this does not actually answer the question.